# linebreak with \lstinline

Tags: listings, line-breaking

Why does `\lstinline` not break lines correctly like with `\begin{lstlisting}`?
The text goes over the documentborder with `\lstinline`.

Thank you!

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    breaklines=true,
    breakatwhitespace=true,
    frame=lines,
    basicstyle=\ttfamily,
}

\begin{document}

    \begin{lstlisting}            
someverylongcode, whichneedssomelinebreak hereandthere, becauseotherwiseitwouldgooverthedocumentborder
    \end{lstlisting}

\lstinline[language=C]!someverylongcode, whichneedssomelinebreak hereandthere, becauseotherwiseitwouldgooverthedocumentborder!

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\lstinline` is `\lstinline`, not `lstonmorethanoneline`, i.e. it's not meant for multiline - display

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`\lstinline` can do linebreaks, but it doesn't stretch the spaces and so it only works in a `\raggedright` or `\sloppy` context:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{listings}

\lstset
{
    breaklines=true,
}

\begin{document}

\lstinline[language=C]!someverylongcode, whichneedssomelinebreak hereandthere, becauseotherwiseitwouldgooverthedocumentborder!

\raggedright
\lstinline[language=C]!someverylongcode, whichneedssomelinebreak hereandthere, becauseotherwiseitwouldgooverthedocumentborder!

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you that works! How can I undo `\raggedright` after `\lstinline`? But I think I will try to avoid long code inline or use normal `lstlistings` instead.